# Нужно перебирать значения в таблице и если они не = 0 , то менять цвет ячейки

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть таблица , нужно как то по очереди проверить все ячейки и если какая то не = 0 , то окрасить ее в другой цвет.Как мне брать значения по очереди и как потом изменить стиль именно этой ячейке?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function colorCells() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("test");
  for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      var cell = tbl.rows[i].cells[j];
      if (cell.textContent != "0") {
        cell.classList.add("green");
      }
    }
  }
}
/*function colorCells() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("test");
  [...tbl.rows].forEach( row => {
    [...row.cells].forEach( cell => {
      if (cell.textContent != "0") {
        cell.classList.add("green");
      }
    })
  })
}*/
```

```css
td {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  text-align:center;
}

.green {
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<table id="test" border="1">
  <tr><td></td><td>0</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>0</td><td></td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>0</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>0</td><td></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<button onclick="colorCells()">Click</button>
```

Comment: что делает cell?

Comment: @ZerusChanel Переформулируйте Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку (сработает не во всех браузерах):

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach(cell => {
  if (cell.innerText != '0') cell.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```